# socket_keepalive configuration for mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, tomcat, mod-jk, keepalive

I have Apache httpd with mod_jk. I have issue with killed connections after long idling period: Apache stops to respond and each HTTP request hangs for 15 minutes. I tried turn off mod_jk connection pooling (with DisableReuse) and the issue disappears.

In the Tomcat documentation it is written:

```
Using this option will have a strong performance penalty for Apache and Tomcat. 
Use this only as a last resort in case of unfixable network problems. 
If a firewall between Apache and Tomcat silently kills idle connections, 
try to use the worker attribute socket_keepalive in combination with 
an appropriate TCP keepalive value in your OS.
```

I tried to use socket_keepalive=true, it became better, but still sometimes HTTP request hangs for 15m.

So it seems like without socket_keepalive 90% of connections are dead, with socket_keepalive 10%, with DisableReuse 0%.

The OS is RedHat Enterprise 6.5. What is appropriate TCP keepalive value? and How it should be configured in my OS to make socket_keepalive works properly?